# Can't update a particular column in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, navicat

It seems like I can't update a particular column in my mysql database. The following queries are executed independently from each other.

```
UPDATE USERS 
SET PUBLIC_TOKEN = 'Something' 
WHERE USER_ID = 1;

UPDATE USERS 
SET PUBLIC_TOKEN = 'SomethingElse' 
WHERE USER_ID = 2;
```

Which leaves me with the following database.

**USERS** table:

```
------------------------
|USER_ID | PUBLIC_TOKEN|
|      1 | Something   |
|      2 | NULL        |
------------------------
```

The second command just keeps 'loading' / 'executing' indefinitely. What are the steps I can take to resolve this issue? I'm happy to log any information if that would clear things up.

Answers are highly appreciated!

Comment: Show more details on how exactly these queries are run. The tags suggest that there's a lot of context missing. What do you mean "The second command just keeps 'loading' / 'executing' indefinitely."? Where is this happening? What happens if you just run these statements in a mysql client shell?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! So, if i just run these queries in navicat (The database management system) the first query finishes in 0.115 seconds. The second one tries to execute but for some reason it never finishes. It could go on for hours since there is no time out limit. What steps could i take to give you more information?

Comment: What happens if you run these queries outside of navicat?

Comment: Okay, so, all of a sudden it does work. In both CML and Navicat. This is very troubling because i have no idea what caused it and how to resolve it when it happens again... Would you have any idea what could cause something like this?

Comment: I don't. Perhaps ask on http://dba.stackexchange.com/, although the format of the question at this stage might not be well received.